# Python unknown file extension .mp4

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am working on a simulation project, however I am unable to create a visual. I started out by running code from matplotlib's documentation (i.e. the code does not belong to me).
When I run the code, I get the error "unknown file extension: .mp4". 
I have installed ffmpeg and checked that it is an updated version.

I am using a Windows computer and Python 3.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']='‪C:\\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

# save the animation as an mp4.  This requires ffmpeg or mencoder to be
# installed.  The extra_args ensure that the x264 codec is used, so that
# the video can be embedded in html5. 
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you share the link to the source from where you have that code please? I would suspect that whatever you changed compared to the original version is likely to cause the error.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-simple-anim-py

Comment: Yeah, so the path to ffmpeg is not in the original example, meaning it's likely wrong. Check with [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it working

Answer (score 9):

```py
writergif = animation.PillowWriter(fps=30)
anim.save('filename.gif',writer=writergif)
```

These lines of code worked for me, got them from https://holypython.com/how-to-save-matplotlib-animations-the-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 2):

I use Windows 10.0.19042, Python 3.10.4, Windows PowerShell 5.1.19041.1320.

1. Download the latest version of FFmpeg [2022-03-28 builds](https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/releases/tag/2022-03-28-git-5ee198f9aa). I use the essentials build zip file.
2. Unzip the file and put the content to `C:\FFmpeg`.
3. Add to path `C:\FFmpeg\bin`, where the executable `ffmpeg.exe` is located.
4. Remove the line `plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']='‪C:\\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'`.
5. Run the modified python code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ran across this issue today and solved it by installing ffmpeg from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows.

I use Windows:

1. I went with the pre-built archive: "ffmpeg-git-full.7z" from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/
2. Extracted with 7-Zip
3. Set the (extracted-files)\bin\ to my PATH.

Now, I can save as .mp4. Also, no need for `plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']='‪C:\\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'`

Answer (score 0):

i succeeded by changing my code snippet:

```
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frame_number, interval=1000 / fps, repeat=False)
ani.save(save_path, fps=fps, writer='ffmpeg')
```

to

```
writer = FFMpegFileWriter(fps=fps)
ani.save(save_path, writer='ffmpeg')
```